# "Error: parse error: premature EOF" error when reading n lines from a json file using jsonlite

Tags: r, json, eof

I have a 3GB json file. I wanted to read first 1000 lines so I can working with how to clean it. When I use this code for import:

```r
json_data <- jsonlite::stream_in(file("2020-04-05-20_cleaned.json"), pagesize = 100)
```

the error I get is:

```r
opening file input connection.
Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       [{"created_at":"Mon Apr 06 00:0
                     (right here) ------^
closing file input connection.
```

first few lines of the "2020-04-05-20_cleaned.json" file looks like so:

```
[{"created_at":"Mon Apr 06 00:04:46 +0000 2020","id":1246951950769434624,"id_str":"1246951950769434624","text":"RT @PampichiNews: #Prevenci\u00f3n #Coronavirus En el municipio de San Mart\u00edn Jilotepeque, Chimaltenango, se observan las medias de distanciamie\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":872612162367361025,"id_str":"872612162367361025","name":"Lis R. SAre","screen_name":"lis_sare","location":"San Francisco Menendez, El Sal","url":null,"description":null,"translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":542,"friends_count":1975,"listed_count":1,"favourites_count":6364,"statuses_count":146437,"created_at":"Thu Jun 08 00:32:06 +0000 2017","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/873012325690822656\/W8H2C0xO_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/873012325690822656\/W8H2C0xO_normal.jpg","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Sun Apr 05 22:49:13 +0000 2020","id":1246932937003749381,"id_str":"1246932937003749381","text":"#Prevenci\u00f3n #Coronavirus En el municipio de San Mart\u00edn Jilotepeque, Chimaltenango, se observan las medias de distan\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/cm492OLpKZ","display_text_range":[0,140],"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":751919185,"id_str":"751919185","name":"Pampich\u00ed News","screen_name":"PampichiNews","location":"Amatitlan, Guatemala","url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/PampichiNews","description":"#Amatitlan: Agencia de noticias independiente. Nuestra mision es informar y generar opinion. WhastApp y Mercadeo \ud83d\udcde 4271 5444","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":42298,"friends_count":4233,"listed_count":148,"favourites_count":39485,"statuses_count":87354,"created_at":"Sat Aug 11 21:15:57 +0000 2012","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"EBEBEB","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme7\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme7\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"990000","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"F3F3F3","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1212032286478274565\/Gm6A4vdp_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1212032286478274565\/Gm6A4vdp_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/751919185\/1517624914","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"#Prevenci\u00f3n #Coronavirus En el municipio de San Mart\u00edn Jilotepeque, Chimaltenango, se observan las medias de distanciamiento entre vendedores y compradores. Buena medida, buen ejemplo \ud83d\udc4f\ud83c\udffc\ud83d\udc4f\ud83c\udffc\ud83d\udc4f\ud83c\udffc https:\/\/t.co\/LJrkYRpcqi","display_text_range":[0,190],"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Prevenci\u00f3n","indices":[0,11]},{"text":"Coronavirus","indices":[12,24]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":1246932923753865216,"id_str":"1246932923753865216","indices":[191,214],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-4zsWoAAHJ5l.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-4zsWoAAHJ5l.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/LJrkYRpcqi","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/LJrkYRpcqi","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/PampichiNews\/status\/1246932937003749381\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":720,"h":540,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":720,"h":540,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":510,"resize":"fit"}}},{"id":1246932923762302983,"id_str":"1246932923762302983","indices":[191,214],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-4zuXYAcLzMb.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-4zuXYAcLzMb.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/LJrkYRpcqi","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/LJrkYRpcqi","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/PampichiNews\/status\/1246932937003749381\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"medium":{"w":308,"h":231,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"small":{"w":308,"h":231,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":308,"h":231,"resize":"fit"}}},{"id":1246932924055855110,"id_str":"1246932924055855110","indices":[191,214],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-400WoAYhMjP.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-400WoAYhMjP.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/LJrkYRpcqi","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/LJrkYRpcqi","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/PampichiNews\/status\/1246932937003749381\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":720,"h":540,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":720,"h":540,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":510,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":1246932923753865216,"id_str":"1246932923753865216","indices":[191,214],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-4zsWoAAHJ5l.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-4zsWoAAHJ5l.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/LJrkYRpcqi","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/LJrkYRpcqi","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/PampichiNews\/status\/1246932937003749381\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":720,"h":540,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":720,"h":540,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":510,"resize":"fit"}}},{"id":1246932923762302983,"id_str":"1246932923762302983","indices":[191,214],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-4zuXYAcLzMb.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-4zuXYAcLzMb.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/LJrkYRpcqi","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/LJrkYRpcqi","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/PampichiNews\/status\/1246932937003749381\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"medium":{"w":308,"h":231,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"small":{"w":308,"h":231,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":308,"h":231,"resize":"fit"}}},{"id":1246932924055855110,"id_str":"1246932924055855110","indices":[191,214],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-400WoAYhMjP.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU3-400WoAYhMjP.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/LJrkYRpcqi","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/LJrkYRpcqi","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/PampichiNews\/status\/1246932937003749381\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":720,"h":540,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":720,"h":540,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":510,"resize":"fit"}}}]}},"quote_count":17,"reply_count":19,"retweet_count":90,"favorite_count":318,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Prevenci\u00f3n","indices":[0,11]},{"text":"Coronavirus","indices":[12,24]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/cm492OLpKZ","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1246932937003749381","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"es"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Prevenci\u00f3n","indices":[18,29]},{"text":"Coronavirus","indices":[30,42]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"PampichiNews","name":"Pampich\u00ed News","id":751919185,"id_str":"751919185","indices":[3,16]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"es","timestamp_ms":"1586131486967"},
{"created_at":"Mon Apr 06 00:04:46 +0000 2020","id":1246951950752649217,"id_str":"1246951950752649217","text":"?? #UnidosPorArgentina #apocalipsis apocalipsis trompetas jesus biblia tengo miedo alemania y francia #covid\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/3ZvFpRl6zh","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1246305369313476610,"id_str":"1246305369313476610","name":"RECUPERE LA CUENTA","screen_name":"hostageveIasco","location":null,"url":null,"description":"CUENTA SPAM","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":183,"friends_count":4,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":160,"statuses_count":435,"created_at":"Sat Apr 04 05:15:39 +0000 2020","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1246640405514518529\/jHjnfEjV_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1246640405514518529\/jHjnfEjV_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1246305369313476610\/1585977520","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"?? #UnidosPorArgentina #apocalipsis apocalipsis trompetas jesus biblia tengo miedo alemania y francia #covid #coronavirus coronavirus cuarentena #Covid_19 #lacasadelpapel4 #QuedateEnCasa sellos alberto hoy vassoura teclado macaco renato #BuenDomingo https:\/\/t.co\/8UGf8txNQe","display_text_range":[0,273],"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"UnidosPorArgentina","indices":[3,22]},{"text":"apocalipsis","indices":[23,35]},{"text":"covid","indices":[102,108]},{"text":"coronavirus","indices":[109,121]},{"text":"Covid_19","indices":[145,154]},{"text":"lacasadelpapel4","indices":[155,171]},{"text":"QuedateEnCasa","indices":[172,186]},{"text":"BuenDomingo","indices":[237,249]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":1246639622505013249,"id_str":"1246639622505013249","indices":[250,273],"additional_media_info":{"monetizable":false},"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/img\/ACLlZJo2rwJkaB-F.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/img\/ACLlZJo2rwJkaB-F.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/8UGf8txNQe","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/8UGf8txNQe","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/hostagevelasco\/status\/1246639766159929346\/video\/1","type":"video","video_info":{"aspect_ratio":[9,16],"duration_millis":89570,"variants":[{"bitrate":832000,"content_type":"video\/mp4","url":"https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/vid\/360x640\/jgUAHSWanHXSeGUp.mp4?tag=10"},{"bitrate":632000,"content_type":"video\/mp4","url":"https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/vid\/320x568\/nCKHMugpIVnT-DvU.mp4?tag=10"},{"content_type":"application\/x-mpegURL","url":"https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/pl\/t3VbCt07x8_5bfMh.m3u8?tag=10"}]},"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":360,"h":640,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":360,"h":640,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":360,"h":640,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":1246639766159929346,"source_status_id_str":"1246639766159929346","source_user_id":1214430662633172992,"source_user_id_str":"1214430662633172992"}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":1246639622505013249,"id_str":"1246639622505013249","indices":[250,273],"additional_media_info":{"monetizable":false},"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/img\/ACLlZJo2rwJkaB-F.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/img\/ACLlZJo2rwJkaB-F.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/8UGf8txNQe","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/8UGf8txNQe","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/hostagevelasco\/status\/1246639766159929346\/video\/1","type":"video","video_info":{"aspect_ratio":[9,16],"duration_millis":89570,"variants":[{"bitrate":832000,"content_type":"video\/mp4","url":"https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/vid\/360x640\/jgUAHSWanHXSeGUp.mp4?tag=10"},{"bitrate":632000,"content_type":"video\/mp4","url":"https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/vid\/320x568\/nCKHMugpIVnT-DvU.mp4?tag=10"},{"content_type":"application\/x-mpegURL","url":"https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/1246639622505013249\/pu\/pl\/t3VbCt07x8_5bfMh.m3u8?tag=10"}]},"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":360,"h":640,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":360,"h":640,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":360,"h":640,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":1246639766159929346,"source_status_id_str":"1246639766159929346","source_user_id":1214430662633172992,"source_user_id_str":"1214430662633172992"}]}},"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"UnidosPorArgentina","indices":[3,22]},{"text":"apocalipsis","indices":[23,35]},{"text":"covid","indices":[102,108]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/3ZvFpRl6zh","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1246951950752649217","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1\u2026","indices":[110,133]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"es","timestamp_ms":"1586131486963"},
{"created_at":"Mon Apr 06 00:04:46 +0000 2020","id":1246951950819758082,"id_str":"1246951950819758082","text":"RT @AyshaRenna: There were sounds of crackers in Delhi. Has #COVID19 left #India? \nWhat an insult to the hapless health workers fighting Co\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":211953796,"id_str":"211953796","name":"Hindustani4Evr","screen_name":"Hindustani4Evr","location":null,"url":null,"description":null,"translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":16,"friends_count":45,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":1143,"statuses_count":1570,"created_at":"Thu Nov 04 18:52:45 +0000 2010","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_normal.png","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Sun Apr 05 16:03:35 +0000 2020","id":1246830853629431809,"id_str":"1246830853629431809","text":"There were sounds of crackers in Delhi. Has #COVID19 left #India? \nWhat an insult to the hapless health workers fig\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/53OeuGqCvn","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1206939287196823552,"id_str":"1206939287196823552","name":"Aysha Renna","screen_name":"AyshaRenna","location":"New Delhi, India","url":"https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/aysharenna\/","description":"Muslim Activist.\nStudent | Jamia Millia Islamia","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":29334,"friends_count":159,"listed_count":15,"favourites_count":206,"statuses_count":339,"created_at":"Tue Dec 17 14:09:05 +0000 2019","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1212072907943206912\/OWFWTGHK_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1212072907943206912\/OWFWTGHK_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1206939287196823552\/1577815803","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"There were sounds of crackers in Delhi. Has #COVID19 left #India? \nWhat an insult to the hapless health workers fighting Corona in adverse conditions even without necessary protective gears? \n #\u0905\u0902\u0927\u0947\u0930_\u0928\u0917\u0930\u0940_\u091a\u094c\u092a\u091f_\u0930\u093e\u091c\u093e","display_text_range":[0,214],"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"COVID19","indices":[44,52]},{"text":"India","indices":[58,64]},{"text":"\u0905\u0902\u0927\u0947\u0930_\u0928\u0917\u0930\u0940_\u091a\u094c\u092a\u091f_\u0930\u093e\u091c\u093e","indices":[193,214]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":6,"reply_count":78,"retweet_count":232,"favorite_count":574,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"COVID19","indices":[44,52]},{"text":"India","indices":[58,64]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/53OeuGqCvn","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1246830853629431809","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"COVID19","indices":[60,68]},{"text":"India","indices":[74,80]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"AyshaRenna","name":"Aysha Renna","id":1206939287196823552,"id_str":"1206939287196823552","indices":[3,14]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1586131486979"},
{"created_at":"Mon Apr 06 00:04:46 +0000 2020","id":1246951947627827201,"id_str":"1246951947627827201","text":"Definitive proof that God is real, and God is good:   \nwhen after three weeks of a quarantine, you find your mom\u2019s\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/mq92jMk3sa","display_text_range":[0,140],"source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web App\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":883619466,"id_str":"883619466","name":"omid safi","screen_name":"ostadjaan","location":"Duke University","url":"http:\/\/www.illuminatedtours.com","description":"Professor of Islamic studies. Jedi-wannabe. Leads educational tours to Turkey and Morocco, Illuminated Tours (https:\/\/t.co\/TgpwCFUf9L). Love & justice, Here & Now.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":15178,"friends_count":6134,"listed_count":318,"favourites_count":16229,"statuses_count":10385,"created_at":"Tue Oct 16 03:42:29 +0000 2012","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"FFF04D","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme19\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme19\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0099CC","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFF8AD","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"F6FFD1","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/455714981497929729\/GY5KFKW7_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/455714981497929729\/GY5KFKW7_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/883619466\/1572536506","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"Definitive proof that God is real, and God is good:   \nwhen after three weeks of a quarantine, you find your mom\u2019s qormeh-sabzi hidden in the back of the freezer!   masha\u2019allah!!! \u2764\ufe0f   \n\n#Qormehsabzi in a time of #Coronavirus.  :-) https:\/\/t.co\/O0HjtMxEO8","display_text_range":[0,231],"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Qormehsabzi","indices":[187,199]},{"text":"Coronavirus","indices":[213,225]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":1246951862315687937,"id_str":"1246951862315687937","indices":[232,255],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU4QHLVWoAE64OS.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU4QHLVWoAE64OS.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/O0HjtMxEO8","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/O0HjtMxEO8","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/ostadjaan\/status\/1246951947627827201\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":2048,"h":1536,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":900,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":510,"resize":"fit"}}},{"id":1246951921413488641,"id_str":"1246951921413488641","indices":[232,255],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU4QKnfXgAEW_sQ.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU4QKnfXgAEW_sQ.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/O0HjtMxEO8","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/O0HjtMxEO8","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/ostadjaan\/status\/1246951947627827201\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":2048,"h":1536,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":900,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":510,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":1246951862315687937,"id_str":"1246951862315687937","indices":[232,255],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU4QHLVWoAE64OS.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU4QHLVWoAE64OS.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/O0HjtMxEO8","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/O0HjtMxEO8","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/ostadjaan\/status\/1246951947627827201\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":2048,"h":1536,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":900,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":510,"resize":"fit"}}},{"id":1246951921413488641,"id_str":"1246951921413488641","indices":[232,255],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU4QKnfXgAEW_sQ.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/EU4QKnfXgAEW_sQ.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/O0HjtMxEO8","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/O0HjtMxEO8","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/ostadjaan\/status\/1246951947627827201\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":2048,"h":1536,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":900,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":510,"resize":"fit"}}}]}},"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/mq92jMk3sa","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1246951947627827201","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1\u2026","indices":[116,139]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1586131486218"}]
```

*couldn't put more lines due to SO characters limit*

Will appreciate it if I can get some your input. Thank you!

EDIT:

```r
#i have tried this too, lead to same error as above
dat <- readLines("2020-04-05-20_cleaned.json", n = 100 )
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(dat))
```

But this one:

```r
fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines("2020-04-05-20_cleaned.json", n = 100), collapse="")))
```

gives me:

```r
Error: parse error: unallowed token at this point in JSON text
          mestamp_ms":"1586131489768"},]
                     (right here) ------^
```

I have seen a lot of posts, none were able to help me.

Comment: `stream_in` is meant to read data in `ndjson` format. The leading `[` that only seems to be on the first line and the commas at the end of the lines makes it seems like that might not be the format you have. It would probably be better to pre-process your data to get it into the correct format first.

Comment: @MrFlick, I finally got it, you were right. the ending comma was throwing things off. Check tis out please: `pagesize=10;
con <- "2020-04-05-20_cleaned.json";
initialJSON = readLines(con, n = pagesize);
collapsedJSON <- paste(initialJSON[2:pagesize], collapse="");
collapsedJSON <- substr(collapsedJSON, 1, nchar(collapsedJSON)-1);
fixedJSON <- sprintf("[%s]", collapsedJSON, collapse=",");

readJSON <- jsonlite::fromJSON(fixedJSON)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MrFlick mentioned:

> `stream_in` is meant to read data in `ndjson` format. The leading `[` that
>   only seems to be on the first line and the commas at the end of the
>   lines makes it seems like that might not be the format you have. It
>   would probably be better to pre-process your data to get it into the
>   correct format first.

I realize that there was comma, so I just removed it from the end of the string, and then re-made json using `sprintf` that fixed for me:

```r
pagesize=10
con <- "2020-04-05-20_cleaned.json"
initialJSON = readLines(con, n = pagesize)
collapsedJSON <- paste(initialJSON[2:pagesize], collapse="")
collapsedJSON <- substr(collapsedJSON, 1, nchar(collapsedJSON)-1)
fixedJSON <- sprintf("[%s]", collapsedJSON, collapse=",")

readJSON <- jsonlite::fromJSON(fixedJSON)
```

Gave me an output like:

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 32
  created_at      id id_str text  source truncated in_reply_to_sta~
  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <lgl>     <lgl>           
1 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "?? ~ "<a h~ TRUE      NA              
2 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "RT ~ "<a h~ FALSE     NA              
3 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "Def~ "<a h~ TRUE      NA              
4 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "RT ~ "<a h~ FALSE     NA              
5 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "RT ~ "<a h~ FALSE     NA              
6 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "RT ~ "<a h~ FALSE     NA              
7 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "RT ~ "<a h~ FALSE     NA              
8 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "RT ~ "<a h~ FALSE     NA              
9 Mon Apr 0~ 1.25e18 12469~ "RT ~ "<a h~ FALSE     NA              
# ... with 152 more variables: in_reply_to_status_id_str <lgl>,
#   in_reply_to_user_id <lgl>, in_reply_to_user_id_str <lgl>,
#   in_reply_to_screen_name <lgl>, user$id <dbl>, $id_str <chr>,
#   $name <chr>, $screen_name <chr>, $location <chr>, $url <chr>,
#   $description <chr>, $translator_type <chr>, $protected <lgl>,
#   $verified <lgl>, $followers_count <int>, $friends_count <int>,
#   $listed_count <int>, $favourites_count <int>, $statuses_count <int>,
#   $created_at <chr>, $utc_offset <lgl>, $time_zone <lgl>,
#   $geo_enabled <lgl>, $lang <lgl>, $contributors_enabled <lgl>,
#   $is_translator <lgl>, $profile_background_color <chr>,
#   $profile_background_image_url <chr>,
#   $profile_background_image_url_https <chr>,
#   $profile_background_tile <lgl>, $profile_link_color <chr>,
#   $profile_sidebar_border_color <chr>, $profile_sidebar_fill_color <chr>,
#   $profile_text_color <chr>, $profile_use_background_image <lgl>,
#   $profile_image_url <chr>, $profile_image_url_https <chr>,
#   $profile_banner_url <chr>, $default_profile <lgl>,
#   $default_profile_image <lgl>, $following <lgl>,
#   $follow_request_sent <lgl>, $notifications <lgl>, geo <lgl>,
#   coordinates <lgl>, place <lgl>, contributors <lgl>,
#   is_quote_status <lgl>, extended_tweet$full_text <chr>,
#   $display_text_range <list>, $entities$hashtags <list>, $$urls <list>,
#   $$user_mentions <list>, $$symbols <list>, $$media <list>,
#   $extended_entities$media <list>, quote_count <int>, reply_count <int>,
#   retweet_count <int>, favorite_count <int>, entities$hashtags <list>,
#   $urls <list>, $user_mentions <list>, $symbols <list>, $media <list>,
#   favorited <lgl>, retweeted <lgl>, possibly_sensitive <lgl>,
#   filter_level <chr>, lang <chr>, timestamp_ms <chr>,
#   retweeted_status$created_at <chr>, $id <dbl>, $id_str <chr>,
#   $text <chr>, $source <chr>, $truncated <lgl>,
#   $in_reply_to_status_id <lgl>, $in_reply_to_status_id_str <lgl>,
#   $in_reply_to_user_id <lgl>, $in_reply_to_user_id_str <lgl>,
#   $in_reply_to_screen_name <lgl>, $user$id <dbl>, $$id_str <chr>,
#   $$name <chr>, $$screen_name <chr>, $$location <chr>, $$url <chr>,
#   $$description <chr>, $$translator_type <chr>, $$protected <lgl>,
#   $$verified <lgl>, $$followers_count <int>, $$friends_count <int>,
#   $$listed_count <int>, $$favourites_count <int>, $$statuses_count <int>,
#   $$created_at <chr>, $$utc_offset <lgl>, $$time_zone <lgl>, ...
```

Thank you MrFlick for helping out.